# Convert two column centered-aligned layout to left-aligned stacked layout depending on item content

Tags: css, flexbox

I have a layout where I have to radio buttons placed like this:

**Column layout:**
[image]

I'd like to place them stacked when they can't fit on the screen, like this:

**Stacked layout:**
[image]

My markup is something like this:

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="radio a">
    <input/>
  </div>
  <div class="radio b">
    <input/>
  </div>
</div>
```

`.radio.a` is aligned to right and `.radio.b` is aligned to left.

I can do it using `display: flex` in the parent with `flex-wrap: wrap;` and `min-width: 50%;` in the `.radio` class.

The problem is that it leaves `.radio.a` at the right when I needed to be aligned to the left.

Comment: `.parent { display:flex; justify-content: space-between;}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about using media queries?

Say each radio needs a min width of 450px, then you'd want your layout to change from stacked to a side-by-side column layout at a minimum viewport width of 900px.

Codepen demo: https://codepen.io/panchroma/pen/PoKewGQ

**CSS**

```
.parent {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

@media (min-width: 900px) {
  .parent {
    flex-direction: row;
  }
  .radio {
    width: 50%;
  }
  .radio.a {
    display: flex;
  }
  .radio.a input {
    margin-left: auto; /* align radio right */
  }
}
```